# Custom View show on center of the screen

Tags: android

i write a custom view class.

i've implement the custom view on Main Layout xml. and set parameter for center of the screen using below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/cs_background"
     android:id="@+id/layout"
     >

   <com.drawings.DrawingView
            android:id="@+id/drawingview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"  
            /> 

 </RelativeLayout>
```

In graphics layout , it show correctly on center postion. But when i execute on simulator, it shows on left top corner.

i've tried to change to implement the layout programmatically, using below code.

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        DrawingView  myView = new DrawingView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layout.addView(myView,params);
        setContentView(linearLayout);
```

But still its show on left top corener.

My drawingview class is,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View
{
    Context context;
    private Path mPath; 
    private Bitmap backgound;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mX,mY;

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE =4;


    public DrawingView(Context c)
    {
        super(c);
        context         = c;
        init();
    }
    public DrawingView (Context c, AttributeSet as)
    {
        super(c,as);
        context         = c;
        init();
    }

    private void init() 
    {
        mPath       = new Path();
        mPaint      = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
        backgound   = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.cs_one);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(backgound, 0, 0, null);
        if(!mPath.isEmpty())
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        invalidate();
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) 
    {
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);

    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) 
    {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);

        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
        {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//          touch_up();
            break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }

}
```

what is the problem? and how to show the custom view on center of the screen. ?

Comment: Post your code with your DrawingView.

Comment: @changweiyao  i've added the drawing view class

Comment: You should implement your onMeasure(int, int) your self.

Comment: try this: params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0);

Comment: @zazgmy i tried to put 0 . but not come to center position.  still it show on left corner only.

Comment: i am also try to implement the codeparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0); but Still its show on left corer only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    this.setMeasuredDimension(backgound.getWidth(), backgound.getHeight());
}
```

implement the onMeasure(int,int)

Comment: i try to implement the code but no use. Still its show on left corer only.

Comment: I try it with my compute. it works. I mean the XML way not the code way.

Comment: I tried, and it works perfectly. check the full example here:
https://github.com/shanwu/shanwu_coding_base/tree/SimplePieChartExample

Comment: i also try to implement the code but no use. Still its show on left corer only

Answer (score 0):

change it

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

to

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Comment: i try to implement the code but no use. Still its show on left corer only.

Answer (score 0):

You should to implement in your custom View class

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
```

**In it you should calculate height and width for your custom View. 
If you need to central your custom View in parent layout - make sure that:**

- custom View height != parent View height

AND/OR

- custom View width != parent View width

For example:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        final int height = mCircleRadius * 2; //calculated
        final int width = getMeasuredWidth(); //parent width

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
```

Now you can use next for your custom View:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

[image]

P.S. You see that `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` gives no effect. The reason is using **parent width** in **onMeasure** instead of calculating exact width.

Comment: i try to implement the code but no use. Still its show on left corer only